# C# - Can't access public function from different class

Tags: c#

I'm starting with C# and I got a problem.

I created a "Windows Form Application" project.

I have a form class named form1 and I added a UserControl class named usercontrol1. In usercontrol1, I have a public function named test which returns 123.

For some reason I can't do this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 UserControl usercontroltest = new usercontrol1();
 usercontroltest.test();
}
```

The error I get is "user control does not contain a definition for"

Comment: Can you show the code for  UserControl class

Comment: Post the UserControl code. Is it marked as static? Is it in a different assembly that hasn't been built?

Comment: Change `UserControl usercontroltest = new usercontrol1();` to `var usercontroltest = new usercontrol1();`

Comment: @evelikov92: Incorrect.  The `var` keyword will infer the type from the expression itself, which is of type `usercontrol1`.  That suggestion does indeed solve the problem.  (At least, it will solve the compiler error and successfully execute.  There could still be underlying design problems here though...)

Comment: I always use `var` when it's obvious from the right hand side what the resulting type will be. I'm lazy and like to type less. Also @David is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you've declared your variable to be of type `UserControl`. That means the compiler will only let you use members declared in `UserControl` and the classes it inherits from. The actual object *is* still of type `usercontrol1` at execution time, but the compiler only cares about the compile-time type of the variable you're trying to use to call the method.

You need to change the declaration to use your specific class:

```
usercontrol1 usercontroltest = new usercontrol1();
```

Or you could use an *implicitly typed local variable*, which would have *exactly* the same effect:

```
var usercontroltest = new usercontrol1();
```

That will fix the immediate problem, but:

- Are you sure you really want to create a *new* instance here, rather than using one which is already on your form?
- You should get into the habit of following [.NET naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) as soon as possible

Comment: damn, makes all sense now! thanks! I didn't get the first question? thanks for the link ;)

Comment: @Th3lmuu90: Well normally you use controls which already exist on the form. created in the Forms Designer. It could well be that you've already got a field of the right type. We don't really know what you're trying to do with this control, but creating a new instance (and assigning the resulting reference to a local variable rather than a field) *may* be a mistake.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why not [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) page ?

Comment: @NullException: Sure, that's slightly better - updated the link. I just used the one that came up searching for ".net naming conventions" :)

Comment: @NullException, that link helps even more, thanks. JonSkeet, I'm kinda new to this, trying to figure out how things work. I have a control (code) and its design, am I doing this wrong but creating an instance of it in the main form class?

Comment: @Th3lmuu90: Well we don't know what you're trying to do, which makes it hard to help, but I'd normally expect you to create the instance in the designer instead...

Comment: @JonSkeet, what I'm trying to do is to have a main form from where I can put/remove usercontrols. Like for instance I click on the menu File->New, I will then load the usercontrols related to that. If I click File->Save, I will load another usercontrol.

Comment: @Th3lmuu90: That doesn't really give me much clue, but we're now quite a long way from your initial question. I suggest you keep trying using the extra information, and ask a new, specific question if you run into more problems.

Comment: ye, that's what I'm going to do. Thanks for ALL the help ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
UserControl usercontroltest = new usercontrol1();
```

While this allocates a new `usercontrol1`, it assigns it to its base class, `UserControl`. `UserControl` has no `test()` method.

You probably want:

```
usercontrol1 usercontroltest = new usercontrol1();
```

instead.